# Shell script to subtartct date

Tags: shell, date, subtraction

I need some help in subtracting each date coming in every 3rd line from the next date coming in every 4th line. See below file part..

```
 Name: John
 Category: Subscriber
 4/6/14 8:00 PM
 4/6/17 7:59 PM
 Name: Hari
 Category: Owner
 4/22/13 6:29 AM
 6/21/32 6:29 AM
 Name: Bob
 Category: Subscriber
 9/9/14 8:00 PM
 9/9/17 7:59 PM
```

Resulting file should be :

```
 Name: John
 Category: Subscriber
 4/6/14 8:00 PM
 4/6/17 7:59 PM
 valid for 1095 days
 Name: Hari
 Category: Owner
 4/22/13 6:29 AM
 6/21/32 6:29 AM
 valid for 7361 days
 Name: Bob
 Category: Subscriber
 9/9/14 8:00 PM
 9/9/17 7:59 PM
 valid for 1095 days
```

Comment: Show what you tried or what ideas you have

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop and do date computation using `date -d`:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while read -r; do
   ((++i))
   echo "$REPLY"
   (((i+1) % 4 == 0)) && d="$REPLY"
   ((i % 4 == 0)) && printf "valid for %d days\n" \
          $(( ($(date -d "$REPLY" '+%s') - $(date -d "$d" '+%s'))/86400 ))
done < file
```

**Output:**

```
Name: John
Category: Subscriber
4/6/14 8:00 PM
4/6/17 7:59 PM
valid for 1095 days
Name: Hari
Category: Owner
4/22/13 6:29 AM
6/21/32 6:29 AM
valid for 7000 days
Name: Bob
Category: Subscriber
9/9/14 8:00 PM
9/9/17 7:59 PM
valid for 1095 days
```

Answer (score 0):

With perl:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -lpe '
    sub diff_time { 
        print "valid for ", int(($d2->epoch - $d1->epoch) / ONE_DAY), " days";
    }
    s/^\s+|\s+$//g;  # trim whitespace
    $d1 = Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p") if $. % 4 == 3; 
    $d2 = Time::Piece->strptime($_, "%m/%d/%y %I:%M %p") if $. % 4 == 0;
    diff_time if $. % 4 == 1 and $. > 1;
    END {diff_time}
' file
```